# How to set the asp.net identity default login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-identity

I'm starting to use the new asp.net identity, specifically the 2.x versions.  I have started from an empty web site because I like to start from the beginning of everything and control everything that goes into my app.  I really do not like automagical stuff.

I have a directory set up to be secured via some settings in my web.config in the directory.  When a non logged in user tries to access a page in this protected directory, the user is being redirected to:

```
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fUsers%2fDefault.cshtml
```

I don't want that.  I want the user to be redirected to:

```
/Login.cshtml?ReturnUrl=*someurl*
```

How do I go about getting the redirection to happen to my login.cshtml file instead of the default entry?

Something things that I have done in the app:

I have set the application's web.config file to have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">    
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.cshtml" timeout="3600"/>    
</authentication>
```

In my startup.cs file, I have:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;  
using Microsoft.Owin;  
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;  
using Owin;  
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(GolfGameApp.Startup))]  
namespace GolfGameApp  
{  
    public class Startup  
    {  
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)  
        {  
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions  
            {  
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,  
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login.cshtml"),  
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logout.cshtml")  
            });  
         }  
    }  
}
```

Talked to some friends and it looks like I have to go to the _PageStart.cshtml file in my directory and use it. I've done that and its working as intended.  if there are some suggestions, let me know.  I'm always trying to do stuff better, so suggest away.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In web.config You have configured `Forms Authentication`, while in your code I see `OWIN` stuff. If you choose OWIN, then you'll have to put in web.config the following.

```
<authentication mode="None">    
</authentication>
```

Also seems you are trying to use MVC in a wrong way.
`loginUrl="~/Login.cshtml"` has no sense in MVC model. Your URLs are formed through Controllers and Routes. *.chtml files are never exposed directly.

ASPNET.Identity, MVC(Razor), Owin, EF are different things. Before starting a project from scratch, you should have do decide what technology and what dlls you are using and how are you  going to combine them.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the answer to what I was looking for and forgot to come back around to this.

Comment: @WallaceB.McClure which was the solution?

Comment: @jstuardo A friend of mine that worked at MSFT at the time said that I should use the _PageStartup.cshtml file in a directory to provide the exact type of security check that I needed to do.  I did.  It works like a champ for razor asp .net pages.